# Fire hover event from JS event function

Tags: jquery, events, scroll, hover

I am currently using the RadTreeNode from telerik.  I would like to make use of some nicer scrollbars which appear on the hover event. For the most part it seems to be working as expected.  However, if you expand an item in the tree node (so that scroll bar would be needed) the scroll bars don't appear until you mouse out and back in again.  I presume this is happening because the hover event is not firing as the mouse is already above the element.  The treeview control has a client side event which fires when a node is expanded.  Is it possible to fire the hover event when this function is fired?

I tried the following but it seems it cannot find the #scrollBars element. I can however see the element in chrome dev tools.

```
 function ClientNodeExpanded(sender, eventArgs) {
   $('#scrollBars').mouseEnter();
}
```

Comment: When you `alert($('#scrollBars').length)` what you see?

Comment: I get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined".

Comment: Sound like you either don't have reference to jQuery or you have conflict with other framework using the `$` sign. Try having `jQuery('#scrollBars').length` instead.

Comment: That has actually returned the length as 1.  Changing my code to: jQuery('#scrollBars').mouseover(); and jQuery('#scrollBars').mouseenter();. Didnt error however, it didnt produce the scrollbars as I expected it to. Mousing out and back in produces them though.

Comment: Are you sure that `RadTreeNode` is using jQuery for their coding? If not I fear you're out of luck - unless you can find in their JS code how they handle those events and mimic that somehow.

Comment: I am not entirely sure what the RadTreeView uses but as the event fires and I get that alert; I would expect to be able to use jQuery to fire the event off.  Maybe I am mistaken about this?  I think it's going to be more to do with slimScroll ([link](http://rocha.la/jQuery-slimScroll)) and me not calling the right events.  Many Thanks for you're help on this.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6763/discussion-between-piercy-and-shadow-wizard)

Answer (score 2):

Methods are [case sensitive in JS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_syntax#Case_sensitivity):

```
$('#scrollBars').mouseenter();
```

or:

```
$('#scrollBars').trigger("mouseenter");
```

Comment: Good to know but unfortunately it didn't solve my issue.  Thanks, Piercy

Answer (score 1):

Try `.mouseover()`.

http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/

Are you using jQuery 1.7? I recall 1.5 had an issue for me where mouseover would not fire if my mouse moved in the div but did not enter it.

Comment: Yes, i am using 1.7 min.  Regards, Piercy edit: and testing mouse over now ;)

Comment: Cool. One way I found to be sure was to alt tab while the mouse is outside the area and place the mouse inside the area, then alt tab back and move around inside the area.